# chrome/google won't allow me to save 2 usernames and passwords for one website

Tags: password-management

I have 2 accounts on the same website with 2 different usernames and passwords.  Google Chrome will only ask to save one of them. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I solved it directly on chrome.

- go to your password management on chrome chrome://settings/passwords
- filter the website on text box (top right) to find your first account
- click on **Add** button to create your second account configuration

And that it ! your new account is synchronized and chrome will suggest both logins when your try to login.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I answered this incorrectly at first, my apologies for that. To clarify your question - does it not prompt you to save when logging in with each account? Or does it overwrite the last saved login?

---

Original Answer

You may need to manually go to passwords.google.com and enter the second account there. Then when you go to log in to the site you should see both options.

Comment: I'm able to reach that password management link but I don't know how to enter a second username and password manually.  Can you help me with that?

Comment: Please expand your answer to provide guidance on the steps to log into a second account.